# How do I make a simple file upload page for my server?

Tags: html

for the past day or so I have been trying to figure out how to make a simple file upload page that lets me upload files to my server. The idea is that when I visit the site, I can upload a file to a folder on the server. I have been looking at sites like Uppy and Filestack but I cannot figure them out at all. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to be precise of your question, are you hosting your own website? are you using any providers out there? which tech stack are you using? what file are you trying to upload?

Comment: What backend are you using? The HTML is pretty trivial ([as per @Mah Es' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058024/3025856). The more involved part is having e.g. a web service or post-back handler that captures that submission and saves it to the appropriate location.

Comment: Hi sorry I just saw these, to answer both questions, I am running a LAMP server. I am trying to upload videos, text, and images to the server. The idea is the index.html is just a file uploader where I can visit the ip and upload files to the server to save them to a folder. For example, the file is uploaded via whatever method which is saved to /mnt/Media for later use.

Answer (score 0):

so do you need HTML only?
to do what you want to do you need a client and a server.
client meaning the HTML page, and the server could be something like a php or python or anything like those.
but, for a simple HTML page with a upload form:

```html
<form action="myBackendAddress" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="myFile">
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```